# What is NInjects equivalent of TryAdd

Tags: ninject

In other DI containers, I have observed TryAddScoped, TryAddTransient, TryAddSingleton etc.

The idea behind Try is to avoid registering multiple times. If a service is already registered, then using Try will not attempt to register again I guess.

With inject

```
Kernel.Bind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
```

So is there any Try equivalent in Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple equivalent.

Performing

```
Kernel.Bind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
Kernel.Bind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
```

will result in in an exception when resolving a `IHttpContextAccessor`, and when resolving `IEnumerable<IHttpContextAccessor>` it will return two `HttpContextAccessor` instances.

However, you can write your own "Try":

### Checking whether Binding already exists

```
if(!Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)).Any())
{
    Kernel.Bind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
}
```

Of course you can also write your own extension method for that:

```
public static class NinjectBindingExtensions
{
    public static void TryBind<T>(
        this IKernel kernel,
        Action<IBindingToSyntax<T>> configureBinding)
    {
        if (!kernel.GetBindings(typeof(T)).Any())
        {
            configureBinding(kernel.Bind<T>());
        }
    }
}
```

### Rebind

One way to work around the issue is to use `.Rebind` instead of `.Bind`. If there's no pre-existing binding it will work just like `.Bind`. And if there's a pre-existing binding, it will replace it. Thus:

```
Kernel.Rebind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
Kernel.Rebind<IHttpContextAccessor>().To<HttpContextAccessor>().InSingletonScope();
```

Resolving `IHttpContextAccessor` will result in one instance of `HttpContextAccessor`.

### Preventing Duplicate Module Loading

In case the problem is not with multiple components / `NinjectModule`s creating bindings for the same type, but rather with loading the same `NinjectModule` twice, you can can prevent duplicate loading by:

```
if(!Kernel.HasModule(typeof(MyModule)))
{
    Kernel.Load<MyModule>();
}
```

Comment: looks like Rebind is the answer.